# Trying to install Node JS, but have problems while make ./configure

Tags: linux, node.js, settings

Thankfully to this article http://habrahabr.ru/post/95960/
I'm trying to install node js properly. But at the moment of configure, I have some problems with not installed packages.

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : not found 
Checking for library execinfo            : not found 
Checking for openssl                     : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : not found 
--- libeio ---
Checking for library pthread             : not found 
Checking for function pthread_create     : not found 
/usr/local/bin/node/deps/libeio/wscript:12: error: the configuration failed (see '/usr/local/bin/node/build/config.log')
```

Can someone please help me to find that ones? I have searched, and tried to install it via apt-get manager, but I haven't reached any result. I'm using Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best way to install/update node is using nvm (Node Version Manager) https://github.com/creationix/nvm

To install
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash`

To install node 4.1 `nvm install 4.1`

Super easy and you can do loads of stuff with nvm. just check the documentation.

If you want to compile, like you are doing, you have to install all of the libraries that are needed.

Comment: Your method hadn't worked for me. I guess nvm is installed, but for second command it exits with message:
`~$ nvm install 4.1`
`No command 'nvm' found, did you mean: ...`
`nvm: command not found`

Comment: It adds some line to your bash profile `The script clones the nvm repository to ~/.nvm and adds the source line to your profile (~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc or ~/.profile).` it should work out of the box, try opening a new bash/shell and execute the command again, `nvm`

Comment: Anyway, I need node.js for less I guess. I'm using symfony2, and trying to install bootsrap and jQuery via bundles, to have native support, but still have no result.

Comment: Yes, I've opened a new terminal box, and it has installed properly. I guess is solves my problem. But now I have 3 different versions :D
My manually created, your version and a version installed via apt-get. I will mark your answer as solving, and keep searching for another problem )

Comment: in ubuntu `node` command is `nodejs` and sometimes makes problems. with nvm you can change version easily, and it will override the system one if you want. `nvm alias default 4.1`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not install Node.js from your default package manager running the below commands?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Also, you might find this article helpful, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Comment: I've tried this way, but where does it live on the computer? I mean the path where it placed.